# Stackapps Overlapping Bug

Tags: bug, design, stackapps

[image: pic]
As you can see, the title of this question is overlapping with some other text.
The ask question button is also not in the right position.
You can see the site [here](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch).
I'm using Google Chrome on a Windows 8.1 computer.
I set zoom size to 100%.
I refreshed the page a few times, but it was the same.

Comment: Cannot reproduce on Mac OS X 10.10 with Chrome 40. I tried both logged in and not logged in, with all extensions disabled. Ditto for Firefox and Safari.

Comment: Could not reproduce on iOS 7 Safari

Comment: Could not reproduce on Windows 8.1 Internet Explorer.

Comment: Are you sure you haven't changed any settings that affect the font size? Your text in that image is way larger than what I see when viewing the page, and that's causing it to all expand to widths that break the page layout. [Here's a comparison of what I see versus what you see.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uskMd.jpg) Using Chrome on Windows 7.